# dependencies of python 27 for RHEL5

Tags: python, linux, rpm, rhel

Essentially I am trying to get Python2.7 to work on Linux EL5, but currently with no success. Really appreciate some pointer from anyone who has done this before.

Anyone happens to know whether there is a repo to get all the dependencies (EL5 rpms if not sources) for Python 2.7?

I could find the RPMs for Python27 EL5 at http://ftp.srce.hr/redhat/test/el5/x86_64/ but still not complete.

```
m000772@hkl20030997 ~]$ rpm -ivh python27-2.7.2-5.2.el5.x86_64.rpm      
error: Failed dependencies:            
libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by python27-2.7.2-5.2.el5.x86_64            python27-libs = 2.7.2-5.2.el5 is needed by python27-2.7.2-5.2.el5.x86_64    

[m000772@hkl20030997 ~]$ rpm -ivh python27-libs-2.7.2-5.2.el5.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:            
libdb-4.8.so()(64bit) is needed by python27-libs-2.7.2-5.2.el5.x86_64
```

Now there is no RPM for libdb-4.8

Comment: Did you try to [search](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=libdb-4.8.so&Search.x=38&Search.y=5&simple=2&dist[]=52&dist[]=0&dl=40&sr=1&field[]=1&field[]=2&srodzaj=1) for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use yum, this command take care of all dependencies.

First check with the following command:

```
# yum search python27
```

And the try with the available version..for example

```
# yum install python27
```

Comment: I searched in these ff repos (epel, atrpms, webtatic-el5) and i did not found python27 for RHEL5. Only python26